# Comparing GWT and Turbo Gears

Tags: gwt, frameworks, web-applications, turbogears2

Anyone know of any tutorials implemented across multiple web application frameworks?

For example, I'm starting to implement GWT's Stock Watcher tutorial in Turbo Gears 2 to see how difficult it will be to do in Turbo Gears 2.

Likewise, I'll be looking for a Turbo Gears 2 tutorial to implement in GWT.

But I hate to re-create the wheel - so I was wondering if anyone was familiar with such projects and/or would be interested in helping me work on such a project.

Thanks,

--Spencer

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to combine the two frameworks, I hope to convince you not to do so.

Most web-frameworks, including Turbogears, have server-side page flow management. A page is served to the user by generating html, user interacts by clicking on links or by posting a form, the browser sends a fresh request to the server, and finally server responds with new html altogether. You AJAX'ify the page by using a js library, or the framework has some support. But, in general, transition from one view to another is done on the server side.

GWT is totally different. There is only a single HTML page in the system. Once this page is downloaded, everything happens on the browser through javascript. When the user clicks on a link, its essentially just a javascript function call. History management is done through fragment urls (the portion after the #).

These two philosophies are poles apart. So apart that I daresay GWT doesn't work well with any server-side web technology. See this discussion on GWT vis-a-vis [JBPM/Struts/Spring Webflow](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/e364565ca294547f). And see this discussion on [GWT v/s JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722259/are-jquery-and-gwt-comparable-frameworks/2722571#2722571).

Comment: Just to clarify - both are great frameworks, but they don't go well together. Like Strawberry Pizza. You got to choose one of them based on your needs, and just forget about the other.

Comment: I didn't think the original poster wanted to mix them, just to compare them.

Comment: Correct - I want to compare them.  How hard is it to do one thing in one framework? and then the same thing in another framework?  The StockWatcher tutorial is incredibly straight forward in GWT.  I still don't quite have my head wrapped around how to get started in Turbo Gears.